# How to mange and save IoT Device logs in Redis to efficiently use in future

Tags: redis, iot

I work for a company that specializes in car IoT devices. These devices are installed in cars and when the car start to work, each second they send a log containing information about the car. We use MQTT as a broker for our logs... 

 I'm working on a micro-service which picks the logs from the MQTT server and then should do the following: For every device it should create a row in a table in our database ( if not yet created) which contains how much this car(device) has worked. And by how much I mean How much time has it been on and how mush distance it has traveled.

Now up to here everything seems simple but the problem is that there is the possibility that a device losses its connection to the internet and doesn't send the logs immediately. How ever the device saves does logs in its memory and whenever it comes back online, it sends the older data in between the newer once, so if for instance it goes of on 11 am and comes back online on 1 pm then the patterns is like this:

- 11 am log (old log)
- 1 am log ( current log)
- 11 am log (old log)
- 1 am log ( current log)
- 11 am log (old log)
- 1 am log ( current log)
  ...

it is possible that the logs of one day be sent on another day and so on...

since there are so many devices and so many logs each second, we couldn't afford to access the database each time a log is received, so we have a `redis` to store are data faster and every few seconds we update the db from the `redis`. It is obvious that each received log represents of `1 second` of work, but My real problem is to calculate the distance each car traveled! For that we need two consecutive logs from the same car so that we can find the `distance delta`. Considering that it is very possible that the logs of a car are mixed, I'm facing some real challenges to handle the data.

 currently I'm saving a key-value pair in Redis which the key looks like this : `deviceid:-:date` and the value contains the `total distance/time` plus some other info. Actually I have a key-value pair stored for every online device that we are receiving form and the `date` is exactly the `date of sending` of that log. As you can see this method doesn't help
to find the distance traveled and since I cant store all the logs I really don't know what to do...

one way I thought is to keep a `sorted-set` for every online car on any date, and in that set, I use the timestamp of the logs as the `score` so that logs are sorted in a logical sequential form. How every I don't know where to go from here and how to efficiently calculate the data I need. 

 If it helps, we are using `golang` as our primary language. sorry about my bad English. Any idea or help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you check RedisTimeSeries?

Comment: Hi there. Are you asking how to calculate difference between successive elements in your sorted set?

Comment: well I don't know that the sorted set idea is a good one or not but if it is, then the calculation wont be a problem, but If you could give your idea on the calculation, that would be great